# In R I'm trying to get the sum of times each value (1, 2, 3) appears per Id within one column using pipe functions and count

Tags: r, group-by, count, sum, tidyverse

I am new to R and am sure the solution is simple, but I am having a hard time figuring out where I'm going wrong.

Apologies if this question has been asked. I did look, but once again, I'm new and it might have gone right over my head. :)

I'm working with a data set "minuteSleep_merged.csv" from the Fitabase Data 4.12.16-5.12.16 folder. I'm trying to determine if the data set is accurate and has insights for my capstone project with the Google Data Analyst Certification.

For backstory, I am using `tidyverse` and have loaded the package into my session in addition to the .csv file I am using.

This is what I have so far:

```
minSleep <- read_csv("minuteSleep_merged.csv")

## getting a summary of the data

head(minSleep)
colnames(minSleep)
n_distinct(minSleep)

## separating the date column into date and time to make it easier to read and aggregate

summ_minSleep <- separate(minSleep, date, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ")

## confirming the column was separated

head(summ_minSleep)

## creating a table that shows the amount of time each participant spent asleep per date

asleep_summ_minSleep <- summ_minSleep %>%
  group_by(Id, date) %>%
  count(value = 1) %>%
  rename(min_asleep = n) %>%
  mutate(hours_asleep = min_asleep/60) 

head(asleep_summ_minSleep)

## doing the same for value 2 (restless)

restless_summ_minSleep <- summ_minSleep %>%
  group_by(Id, date) %>%
  count(value = 2) %>%
  rename(min_restless = n) %>%
  mutate(hours_restless = min_restless/60) 

head(restless_summ_minSleep)

## and one more time for value 3 (awake)

awake_summ_minSleep <- summ_minSleep %>%
  group_by(Id, date) %>%
  count(value = 3) %>%
  rename(min_awake = n) %>%
  mutate(hours_awake = min_awake/60)

head(awake_summ_minSleep)
```

I thought I was onto something when I got the first table `asleep_summ_minSleep` to run properly.

But my next thought was, to know if the data set should be kept for analysis or removed in the cleaning process, I would also need to know how many hours each participant spent awake and restless per day.

So, I created a separate table for each value (1 = asleep, 2 = restless, 3 = awake). As you can see each table has a different name with column names that create a clear distinction.

Also, as a side note, I created a separate table for each because I couldn't figure out how to make a pipe that would contain all this information in one table. That will be my next learning adventure.

Anyway, back to the task at hand. You all can probably already see what my issue is and the cause, but, to spell it out, while each table is correctly labeled and shows the correct corresponding **value** column, the data within the columns **hours_asleep**, **hours_restless**, and **hours_awake** are exactly the same.

It took an unfortunate amount of time and web searching to create the first table, but with trial and error I thought I was on to something, but this clearly shows I'm off somewhere so I'm seeking help.

Here is a link to an R Markdown file: https://5b69b06b6e8d44fe9dd87e7ae606c95a.app.rstudio.cloud/file_show?path=%2Fcloud%2Fproject%2FminSleep_help.html

Any suggestions, hints, theories, really anything, would be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Hello Tabitha. Please share a glimpse of your data, for example `print(summ_minSleep)` or better `dput(summ_minSleep)` to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: I suspect `count(value = 1)`  and `count(value = 2)` are not doing what you expect. In R, `value = 1` means you are setting the variable `value` to be 1, and then you are counting all the observations, but you probably want `filter(value == 1) %>% count()` and `filter(value == 2) %>% count()` to count how many rows have value of 1 and value of 2.  Or use `count(value)` to get the number of observations with each `value`. Or `count(value, wt = WEIGHTING_VARIABLE)` if there is a column with minutes etc. to measure how much time is related to each observation row.

Comment: @JonSpring I'm going to try that now. Thank you!

Comment: @JonSpring `count(value)` worked beautifully and was the solution to aggregating all the data in one table. Thank you!!